# How to create custom date display format in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, datetime

I have created content type for an events in which I mentioned multiple values for date field. I want to display date like Nov. 2, 6 & 8   or Nov. 2-5, 12 2014 & Jan 22 2015

After some research I am able to create a view of event date field like

*Nov 23 2014, Nov 26 2014, Nov 30 2014, Jan 03 2015 to Jan 05 2015*

But still not getting format I want like

*Nov 23, 26, 30 2014 & Jan 03-05 2015*

Comment: It's about to 4 days that I am working on it, still not get perfect guidence

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with coding then go for template file changes.
You have to do changes in node.tpl.php.

Else you can do also without coding refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375674/how-can-a-custom-drupal-date-format-be-added

If you have created view for event display then it is easy to display date field as you want.
Go to date fields setting. There is a option for formatter. Like below screenshot. Here you can add custom date display format.

[image]

Comment: Ok let me know if you are getting any issue in this scenarios.

Comment: I don't think adding a custom dare format is going to help here, as there's conditional logic necessary to collate dates by arbitrary criteria. Given that your incidence and interval pattern  is variable, my suggestion would be to allow the user to input multiple date values and then loop through those via theme preprocessing functions or in a specific node--type or field-- template override rather than node.tpl.php. If you will be testing for date conflicts, that may further complicate solutions proposed here.

Comment: @murraybiscuit is there any tutorial that I can follow for this?

Comment: The solution gets pretty complicated depending on the parameters. Getting the fields out of the node and grouped into a multi-dimensional array is easy. Grouping the array by year and then by month gets more tricky. Then you sort the array. Then you loop through to combine it. What if a date falls across two months? What if it falls across two years? I'd say the Drupal parts of this are easy. The php stuff is where it's going to require some fiddly conditional logic & exceptions.

Comment: @murraybiscuit, Ok I will go through this, Big Thanks for your support :)

Comment: Cool. It's a fair bit of work. If you manage to make it work (elegantly), paste it back here as the answer. Even if it's just the php logic, someone else could use it for a display formatter module, or it could be a new feature for the Date contrib project. I could see a general use case for this code.